# How to set tab height in android tabwidget from xml?

Tags: android

I tried the solution:

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,100));
```

but I want to do this in XML.

This is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                style="@style/tab"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

I tried to set the height of TabWidget but no results.

I use a custom view for the single tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_tab"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txv_tab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_tab"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
    </TextView>

    <View android:id="@+id/tab_border" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to set the relativelayout height but every time I get fullscreen-height tabs.

How can I set the height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to set tab height in android tabwidget from xml. I never found a way to do this.
To avoid the problem of bad effect I have created a very simple class like this:

```
public class TipoDisp 
{ 

  public static int alt_tabs(Context cont)
  {
    int alt;
    int dx, dy;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = cont.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();


    dx = metrics.widthPixels;
    dy = metrics.heightPixels;
    if (dx < dy)
        alt = dy/15;
    else
        alt = dy/10;

    return alt;
   }
}
```

and then, in the activity I use something like this:

```
    int alt = TipoDisp.alt_tabs(myactivity.this);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = alt;
    .....
```

hope this helps

Comment: I mark this as answer because searching on internet there is no way to do what i want, but yours is the only way I found to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Let say, We want to set height of the first tab then what you have to do is:

```
 mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height=100;
```

mTabHost= it is my own tabhost. Place your tabhost name there
I set height 100dp. Now you change based on your requirements. Thanks